# App crashes when changing intent?

Tags: android, android-activity

I set an imageview to change my activity onClick, for some reason it crashes each time I click the imageview on my device. Any ideas? I feel as if this is a very general answer that I am missing. Also if you have any reading material you could link related to my mistake it would help me greatly. Thank you!

Main Activity

```
    package com.gcomcode.oakgang;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView bioicon;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ImageView musicicon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.musicicon);
    ImageView galleryicon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.gallery);
    ImageView connecticon = (ImageView) findViewById (R.drawable.connecticon);
    ImageView contacticon = (ImageView) findViewById (R.drawable.contacticon);
    ImageView eventsicon = (ImageView) findViewById (R.drawable.eventsicon);
            }
public void bioClick() {
     bioicon  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.bioicon);
     bioicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent bioIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BioActivity.class);
             startActivity(bioIntent);

         }

     });



}
}
```

and here is the corresponding layout

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context="com.gcomcode.oakgang.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/oakganglogo" 
         />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="216dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bioicon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bioicon"
        android:onClick="bioClick" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/musicicon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/musicicon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/galleryicon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eventsicon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eventsicon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contacticon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contacticon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/connecticon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/connecticon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the activity I am trying to open

```
    package com.gcomcode.oakgang;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class BioActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bio_activity);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
public void bioClick() {
```

to this:

```
public void bioClick(View view) {
```

**because in order for an onClick method to be called from the xml (layout file), that onClick method has to take in exactly one parameter, a View parameter.** (The view that gets passed into the method is whichever view called it - whichever view was pressed. This is useful if you want more than one view to call the same onClick method, because then you can use the view variable to figure out which view called it, and respond accordingly.)

Now, another problem with your code:

If you make that change I wrote, then it will probably stop crashing, because now it will be able to find the right onclick method. But the first time you click on bioicon, it won't take you to a new activity. You will find that you have to click it TWICE to make it go to a new activity. That is because the first time you click it, it runs the bioClick method. But the only thing that method does is to change the onClick method for the ImageView from "bioClick" to the new internal method. If you want the activity to change the FIRST time you click the bioicon ImageView, change your method to look like this:

```
public void bioClick() {
     Intent bioIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BioActivity.class);
     startActivity(bioIntent);
}
```

This part of the code:

```
bioicon  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.bioicon);
bioicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent bioIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BioActivity.class);
             startActivity(bioIntent);

         }

     });
```

is how you set an onClickListener programmatically, in code. If you set an onClickListener in your xml layout file (by using `android:onClick="bioClick"`), then you do not need to set your onClickListener programmatically as well. Do one or the other, but not both.

While I am at it, I will also point out that unless you have more code in your onCreate method of your first activity than you showed here, there is absolutely no point to doing this:

```
    ImageView musicicon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.musicicon);
    ImageView galleryicon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.gallery);
    ImageView connecticon = (ImageView) findViewById (R.drawable.connecticon);
    ImageView contacticon = (ImageView) findViewById (R.drawable.contacticon);
    ImageView eventsicon = (ImageView) findViewById (R.drawable.eventsicon);
```

You only need to "get" your views into variables if you plan on doing something with them afterward. (Like setting Listeners on them, changing text, or whatever.)

Comment: Thank you! That all makes total sense now. Those views are going to be used in a similar fashion as the bioicon.

Comment: Oh, also, while I'm at it. If you call findViewById on your ImageViews, I'm pretty sure you should be doing R.id.bioicon, not R.drawable.bioicon. The drawable is the source for the imageview, but that's taken care of in the layout file, and you don't want your code to access/change the original drawable, you want it to access the actual ImageView, whose ID is R.id.bioicon.